# What type is a Vue 3 template function ref?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-sfc

Vue 3 allows a function to be used to assign a ref

```js
const target = ref<Element>()

const functionRef = (ref: Element) => {
  target.value = ref
}
```

```html
<template>
  <div :ref="functionRef" />
</template>
```

However, Volar and TypeScript will both complain that the `:ref="functionRef"` binding has a type mismatch.

> Type '(ref: Element) => void' is not assignable to type 'string | Ref | ((ref: Element | ComponentPublicInstance<{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, false, ComponentOptionsBase<any, any, any, any, any, any, any, any, any, {}>> | null) => void) | undefined'.
>
> runtime-dom.d.ts(1479, 3): The expected type comes from property 'ref' which is declared here on type 'ElementAttrs'

What is the type of a function ref?

Answer (score 3):

```js
import { ComponentPublicInstance } from 'vue';
const functionRef = (ref: ComponentPublicInstance | null | Element) => {
  target.value = ref
}
<div :ref="functionRef" />
```

Answer (score 2):

The `runtime-dom.d.ts` link contains the following definition.

```js
type ReservedProps = {
  key?: string | number | symbol
  ref?:
    | string
    | RuntimeCore.Ref
    | ((ref: Element | RuntimeCore.ComponentPublicInstance | null) => void)
  ref_for?: boolean
  ref_key?: string
}
```

This definition can be found in the source [here](https://github.com/vuejs/core/blob/9c304bfe7942a20264235865b4bb5f6e53fdee0d/packages/runtime-dom/types/jsx.d.ts#L1314).

The important part is third union type for `ref?`

```js
(ref: Element | RuntimeCore.ComponentPublicInstance | null) => void
```

This means you can define a reusable type for the `ref` argument as follows.

```js
// this may not be necessary depending on where you put this definition
import * as RuntimeCore from '@vue/runtime-core'

type VueRef = (ref: Element | RuntimeCore.ComponentPublicInstance | null) => void
```

You can now update your function ref with the new type for the arg

```js
const target = ref<Element>()

const functionRef = (ref: VueRef) => {
  target.value = ref
}
```